# While loop causes program to hang

Tags: c, infinite-loop, do-while

I am working on a class assignment (non-graded) and am unclear as to why this piece of code results in my program "hanging" vs running through the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int nbStars = 0;        // User defines the number of stars to display
    int nbLines = 0;        // User defines the number of lines on which to print

    // Obtain the number of Stars to display
    printf("Enter the number of Stars to display (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d", &nbStars);
    getchar();

    //   Limit the values entered to between 1 and 3
    do {
        printf("Enter the number of Stars to display (1-3): ");
        scanf("%d", &nbStars);

        if (nbStars < 1 || nbStars > 3) puts("\tENTRY ERROR:  Please limit responses to between 1 and 3.\n");
    } while (nbStars < 1 || nbStars > 3);
}
```

Comment: Where is it hanging? At getchar maybe?

Comment: Start by adding  \n to the end of the displayed messages. Also: don't repeat yourself; you can put the first scanf into the loop, too ( := use only one scanf() )

Comment: In what way is it "hanging"? What are the symptoms?

Comment: Your program is not "hanging", it is waiting for you to enter a character in `getchar()`.

Comment: It is unlikely it hangs for `getchar` as it usually just reads (and in this case, discards) the newline character following the entered number.

Comment: What are your platform and compiler?  I compiled this program, and it doesn't hang.  If I type "1<Enter>1<Enter>" in response to the prompts, the program closes.

Comment: Using a windows 7 system.  GNU GCC compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else going on because your code works on both Linux with GCC and Windows 7 cygwin with GCC. Can you provide more details about the input you are using and your environment?

Try this code to see if you get different behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int nbStars = 0;        // User defines the number of stars to display
    int nbLines = 0;        // User defines the number of lines on which to print

    // Obtain the number of Stars to display
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the number of Stars to display (1-3): ");
        scanf("%d", &nbStars);

        if (nbStars < 1 || nbStars > 3)
        {
            puts("\tENTRY ERROR:  Please limit responses to between 1 and 3.\n");
        }
    }while (nbStars < 1 || nbStars > 3);

    printf("You entered %d\n", nbStars);
    return( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Output is usually line buffered, if you don't print a new line (`"\n"`), you won't see any output. Your program is not hanged, it's just waiting for input.

Note: if you're using `do` while loops, why do you ask for input before the loop? Your program will enter the loop even with good input. And it would work even without `do` as `nbStars` is initialized to `0`.

```
while (nbStars < 1 || nbStars > 3) {
    printf("Enter the number of Stars to display (1-3): \n");
    scanf("%d", &nbStars);

    if (nbStars < 1 || nbStars > 3) puts("\tENTRY ERROR:  Please limit responses to between 1 and 3.\n");
}
```

Comment: Very strange.  I'm still getting just a black screen.